# Atomic registry not working

Tags: docker

I followed the quick start guide(http://docs.projectatomic.io/registry/latest/registry_quickstart/administrators/index.html) to install the atomic registry on an EC2 instance. After installation I cannot login to the web console. I get redirected to the oauth server and after entering any username and password it redirects back to the console with token but it says access denied. The logs contain the below messages

```
May 17 09:12:32 ip-172-31-8-203.us-west-2.compute.internal dockerd-current[5747]: I0517 09:12:32.2628251 scheduler.go:160] Failed to schedule pod: default/docker-registry-1-deploy
May 17 09:12:32 ip-172-31-8-203.us-west-2.compute.internal atomic-registry-master[11798]: I0517 09:12:32.2628251 scheduler.go:160] Failed to schedule pod: default/docker-registry-1-deploy
May 17 09:12:48 ip-172-31-8-203.us-west-2.compute.internal dockerd-current[5747]: 2017/05/17 09:12:48 Couldn't get user data: 403 Forbidden
May 17 09:12:48 ip-172-31-8-203.us-west-2.compute.internal atomic-registry-console[11799]: 2017/05/17 09:12:48 Couldn't get user data:403 Forbidden
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problems and decided to set it up by using master and registry of versions 1.5.1 and 1.2.1

Analyzing the login problem lead me to the error message that roles are not present in the registry.

After searching for some days how to solve this, I found a fresh opened bug report which states that the missing roles are a bug ...

Happened some days ago.

Regards, D.

Comment: Could you please share the link the bug report in the answer?